# Hide inline edit image button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem. I can't figure what's wrong with my code. All i need to do is to hide the inline edit image button whenever the $principal_amt==$balance_amt but my code does nothing. Here's my code:

// Edit image button:

```
<td <?php echo  $rowclass; ?>>
<?php echo  $html->linkWithImage('Edit','cashadvance/update/' . $cashadvance["id"], array(), 'editicon.png', array('class' => 'try')); ?>
</td>
```

//JS:

```
$("#principal_amt").change(function(){
        var principal = $("#principal_amt").val();
        $("#balance_amt").val(principal);

            if("#balance_amt" == "#principal"){
             $('.try').show(true);
            }
            else{
            $('.try').hide(true);}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing with the the ID's not there values in `if("#balance_amt" == "#principal")`

that should be :

```
$("#principal_amt").change(function(){
    var principal = $("#principal_amt").val();
    $("#balance_amt").val(principal);

        if($("#balance_amt").val() == principal){
         $('.try').show(true);
        }
        else{
        $('.try').hide(true);}
    });
```

Comment: Again, that condition will always return true.

Comment: @adeneo `$("#balance_amt").val(principal);` in this line he set the balance amount equal to principal amount and every time its equal to principal, its a unclear question from OP.

Answer (score 0):

you compare two different string:

```
if("#balance_amt" == "#principal"){
```

This means: if the string #balance_amt = #principal then.. but this is always false.

If I understand well your problem try to change to this your code:

```
$("#principal_amt").change(function(){
    var principal = $("#principal_amt").val();
    $("#balance_amt").val(principal);

        if($("#balance_amt").val() == principal){
          $('.try').show(true);
        }
        else{
          $('.try').hide(true);
        }
    });
```

In this case is always true...

Comment: Now of course, as you've just set the value of `#balance_amt` to `principal`, the condition will always be true ?

Comment: yes now the condition is always true.. isn't celar what the OP wanna do.. @adeneo